# Where did they hide the weapon loadout screen?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In an early mission (no spoilers from me!), I had just found what I am guessing is your first sniper rifle. Convieniently, a nice little pop-up told me "press this to open the loadout menu!". So I did. Slapped on a sniper rifle and off I went. It took all of 30 seconds to realise I also have a shotgun equipped. The only game I have ever actually enjoyed a shotgun in was Doom, and this ain't it. So I went back to the menus to take off the shotgun. One less weapon to scroll through, right?

Well, not so fast. I can't find the blasted menu anywhere! The only menu I would think to find it under is the "Squad" menu, and it only seems to have skill trees.

Where do I find the loadout menu? I was just in there. I doubt EA would have patched it out between the time I found the rifle and the time I wanted rid of the shotgun...

Comment: Don't get too anti-shotgun. Unlike in the previous MEs, shotguns appear to not suck in ME3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your weapon load out can only be adjusted in three places:

**At the start of a mission**, you'll be given the opportunity to tailor your load out to the mission at hand.

**At weapon benches**, in addition to allowing you to install upgrades, benches will allow you to swap out guns mid-mission. Between missions, you'll find weapon benches aboard the Normandy, in the Shuttle Bay, and on the Citadel in the gun range at the Spectre office, in the Embassy Level.

**When picking up a new weapon**, as you noted, when you find a new weapon in the field, you're given the opportunity to equip it, and adjust the rest of your gear to compensate. However, unlike at a bench or the start of a mission, you cannot adjust your weapon mods at this time.

Comment: There is a weapon bench in the Normandy, just next to the shuttle pilot.

Comment: You often encounter weapon benches shortly after you find a new weapon.